# How to prioritize signs

Tags: quadratics

Make n the subject of the formula:
$$ P=400n^2-1280 $$
Why is the answer
$$ n= \sqrt\frac{P+1280}{400} $$
And not
$$ n=\sqrt{\frac{P}{400}+1280} $$

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible to divide by 400 first thing you do. However, when you do this, you have to divide every term of the equation by 400, including the negative 1280 term.

$$P = 400n^2 - 1280$$
$$\frac{P}{400} = n^2 - \frac{1280}{400}$$
$$\frac{P}{400} + \frac{1280}{400} = n^2$$
$$\frac{P + 1280}{400} = n^2$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{P + 1280}{400}} = n$$
$$n = \sqrt{\frac{P + 1280}{400}}$$

A simple example should make it quite easy to see why you have to do this.

$$2 + 2 = 4$$
$$2 + 1 = 2$$
$$3 = 2$$

So, in order to have all of mathematics work, this would be correct.

$$2 + 2 = 4$$
$$1 + 1 = 2$$
$$2 = 2$$

For more information look here:
https://youtu.be/oOmxNr26fWs

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have $$P+1280=400n^2$$ and then you must divide the whole sum by $$400$$ so you get $$\frac{P+1280}{400}=n^2$$
If you divide at first by $400$ you will get
$$\frac{P}{400}=n^2-\frac{1280}{400}$$

Comment: Why cant u divide first then plus. Is there any rule you must follow?

Comment: No, at first i have added $1280$ and then we can divide by $400$

Comment: Even if you divide everything by $400$ first regardless, you will still get the same answer.

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: by the second way you will get the same answer, why do you don't think so?

Comment: Your answer and the possible answer are not equal. 1280 isnt 512000

Comment: you would have to multiply 1280 by 400 so as to make them a single fraction

Comment: No you must divide $1280$ by $400$!

Comment: you must times both numerator and denominator by 400 right?

Comment: 400 is the common denominator